# No route matches [GET] "/answers/data.xls"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, xls

Following http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

But using rails 4, and ruby 2.0.

My rake routes is:

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
root GET      /                                      access#index
     GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
```

and I've updated my mime file to include:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls
```

(I've also tried this, per the video:)

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
```

`data.xls.erb` exists in my views, and I've defined data in my `answers_controller` like this:

```
def data
    @data_fields = DataField.all
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xls
    end
end
```

yet when I visit `http://localhost:3000/answers/data.xls` I get `No route matches [GET] "/answers/data.xls"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL

```
http://localhost:3000/answers/data.xls
```

doesn't match the route

```
GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
```

Note that the route isn't expecting `data.xls`, it's expecting `data/:id.xls`.

Comment: Thanks – I assumed the id was optional since it is not necessary for `html` renders.